# PostGIS function to get the corresponding intersection matrix pattern for any of the 8 spatial relationships between two geometries

Tags: postgis, de-9im, ogc-sfa, ogc-sfs

I have a quick and very simple question for which I have not (yet) been able to find an answer:

is there a PostGIS function to get the [intersection matrix pattern](https://postgis.net/docs/using_postgis_query.html#general-spatial-rel) corresponding to any of the 8 relationships between two geometries (`ST_Contains`, `ST_Crosses`, `ST_Disjoint`, `ST_Equals`, `ST_Intersects`, `ST_Overlaps`, `ST_Touches`, and `ST_Within`)?

E.g.: `ST_GetIntersectionMatrixPattern('ST_Contains') -> T*****FF*`

Comment: No, but spatial predicates are quite standardized - with some minor contextual derivations or additions between topology libraries - see the [Wikipedia article](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/DE-9IM). In addition to that, the two-parameter signature of [`ST_Relate`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Relate.html) returns the DE-9IM pattern of two geometries.

Comment: Also note that some named predicates are based on different IM patterns for different geometry input types (e.g. ST_Crosses).